# How do I change the UX here to signify rise or drop in percentage

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, chatbots

I am trying to model a conversational chatbot and this is a relatively new area in terms of UX for me. I need to be able to set percentage increase or decrease alerts for my cryptocurrency bot something along the lines of "Alert me if BTC falls by 80% or ETH rises by 40%" I have the current UX designed as follows

[image]

What is the best way for me to get increase or decrease from the user? Currently if they mean -80, it translates to 80% fall in my bot but I dont feel this is optimal as the general user doesnt think in terms of negative numbers.

Comment: Why not just tell your user -80% as well?

Comment: @Wanda the user can set any values from 1 to 99 and its not feasible to put 99 buttons and that is only positive, if we take -99 to 99 , thats 199 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit enough, consider asking 'Percentage increase or decrease?' after the user chooses the alert type of 'Percentage'. The options (for the user to choose) would then be 'Increase' or 'Decrease'. This way the user only has to enter a number for the last step.

Comment: thanks man, i thought about this at the start, my only concern was an increase in the step to gather this data but from the looks of it, it seems the user would be more confused on what to enter if negative/positive numbers are to be captured in 1 step

Comment: but 1 doubt though, when I already have buttons "Increase" and "Decrease" what should the text say. 

The text saying "Percentage increase or decrease" and then showing "increase" and "decrease" as buttons, isnt that redundant?

Comment: Np glad I could help. I agree, although an extra input required by the user, seems a vital step for the user to clearly understand.

Following the conversational approach, how about something like (after they select 'Percentage' for the alert type), "Okay, do you want to be alerted about a percentage increase or decrease?"